# PowerShell: exclude node_modeules from Get-ChildItem becuase of long paths

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script to find `csproj` files in a repository, but it fails beause many of the patshs under `node_modules` are longer than 260 characters. I know there are no `.csproj` files in this folder, so I can just exclude it... but how?

Not like any of these:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Recurse -Filter *.csproj -Exclude node_modules
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Recurse -Filter *.csproj -Exclude **\node_modules
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Recurse -Filter *.csproj -Exclude **\node_modules\**\*
```

Is it possible?

Or should I just ingore the errors?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use AlphaFS library - it handles long file names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path folder_path -Recurse  | ? { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'folder_you_want_to_search' }
```